# When to use doOnTerminate vs doOnUnsubscribe?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I need to be notified when something subscribes to my observable. I also need to be notified that the observable has either errored or completed. So I thought I should use `doOnSubscribe`:

> register an action to take when an observer subscribes to an
>   Observable

and `doOnTerminate`:

> register an action to take when an Observable completes, either
>   successfully or with an error

Then I saw `doOnUnsubscribe`:

> register an action to take when an observer unsubscribes from an
>   Observable

and thought the symmetry of `doOnSubscribe`/`doOnUnsubscribe` would be better.

So, will `doOnTerminate` always be called before `doOnUnsubscribe`? If I just want to know that things are "done", does it really matter which I choose?

Comment: DoOnTerminal has following definition: "Modifies the source Observable so that it invokes an action when it calls onCompleted or onError". It is totally different from doOnUnsubscribe. If you have a subscription to a hot observable which you unsubscribe from you will get doOnUnsubscribe call and the observable will continue producing values. If you want to get notified if the observable is 'done' (onComplete, onError) you would use doOnTerminate. If you want to know about the successful completion, I would use doOnCompleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way unsubscribe happens in your reactive flow will determine which one from `doOnUnsubscribe` or `doOnTerminate` you can use. The following can be the cases:

**Observable completion/error triggers unsubscribe**
In such a scenario both `doOnTerminate` and `doOnUnsubscribe` will be called with `doOnTerminate` being called first.

The below example will print both *terminated* and *unsubscribed*.

```
Subscription subscribe = Observable.empty() // source terminates immediately
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
    .doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println("terminated"))
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> System.out.println("unsubscribed"))
    .subscribe();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
subscribe.unsubscribe(); // by this time already unsubscribe would have happened
```

**Programatic call to unsubscribe before Observable completes**
In such a scenario only `doOnUnsubscribe` will be called. The chance of this happening is more prevalent when you have a source which runs infinitely or a source which is hot like an observable for user clicks.

The below example will only print *unsubscribed*.

```
Subscription subscribe = Observable.never() // source never terminates
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println("terminated"))
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> System.out.println("unsubscribed"))
    .subscribe();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
subscribe.unsubscribe(); // this will trigger unsubscribe
```

Comment: What about RxJava 2? It doesn't have `unsubscribe()`, but has `dispose()` and `doOnUnsubscribe()`.

Comment: @soshial I don't see `doOnUnsubscribe()`?