# How to test the spring cloud gateway WebFilter with doFinally/doOnTerminate ？

Tags: spring-webflux

I created two WebFilters in my gateway application which based on spring cloud gateway.

The first one for add some operation log as following.

```
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    ServerHttpResponse response = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
    webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange).doOnTerminate(() ->{
       operationLog.sendOperationLog(serverWebExchange, uri, "", response.getStatusCode().value())
    })
  }
```

I try to test it with spring boot test as following.

```
@MockBean
OperationLog operationLog;

webTestClient.post().uri("/test")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

verify(operationLog, times(1))
                .sendOperationLog(any(ServerWebExchange.class), any("/test"), eq(""), eq(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
```

The test failed, seems that doOnTerminate callback in no executed.

But It executed when I debug it in my env.

Comment: The test is not stable. There are 3 tests for this scenario. There is one or two failed for every time.

Comment: reading this might clear up the usages of doOnTerminate vs doOnUnsubscribe vs doOnCompleted and their usages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407842/when-to-use-doonterminate-vs-doonunsubscribe

Comment: Looks like you forgot to call subscribe() method on your webTestClient

Comment: @YauhenBalykin you dont call subscribe on webtestclients you can lookup the usage here of how to use the webTestClient https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/ you should in general never use subscribe in a webflux application, not in the application itself, and never in any tests.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I read that and I am clear about the difference. But My question is how to make sure the doTermination is executed before I verify it.

Comment: I have to Thread.sleep(100) before verify to make the test case passed.  But I know it still a problem as in different we have to sleep more time to wait the doFinally finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito#timeout to wait until method operationLog.sendOperationLog is invoked. Something like this:

```
verify(operationLog, timeout(100))
                .sendOperationLog(any(ServerWebExchange.class), any("/test"), eq(""), eq(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
```

In this case mockito check invocation during 100 millis.